# How to adjust data's position using Rotativa in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor

I am working on a invoicing project and I want to print in PDF contents from parameters in a given method. I am not familiarized with ***Rotativa*** and I have been finding examples over the internet but I did not find information related on how to adjust/position specific data. Most of the examples are related on how to print pdf having a specific entire view(which I am not interested in).

I have this:

**View:**

```
 //rest of the code

 <a href="@Url.Action("PrintInvoice", "Reportes", new {name = "myname", address = "myaddress"})">PRINT</a>

 //rest of the code
```

**Controller:**

```
 public ActionResult PrintInvoice(string name, string address)
    {
        // I want to position name and address in a specific position using an A4 paper

        var q = new ActionAsPdf("");
        return q;
    }
```

I want to adjust the data from parameters in a specific position in a A4 paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust position just by using HTML and CSS. Try this:

```
public ActionResult PrintInvoice(string name, string address)
{
    return new ActionAsPdf("Print", new { name, address });
}

public ActionResult Print(string name, string address)
{
  //use code to render your view and try to adjust position using HTML and CSS.
}
```